# Problems With Borders and Alignment With CSS

Tags: html, css

1. I want the elements within my top `logo` div to be centered. I'm not sure quite how to do that.
2. My `navigation` div is not matching up with the `logo` div. There is still space between the divs even tho I have set the margins to 0px.
3. My placeholder graphic for some reason has more padding on the bottom than anywhere else within the `logo` div. What do I need to do to change that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>css example</title>

<style type="text/css">

#logo {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(255,200,0);
    margin: 0px;
}

#logo p {
    display: inline;
}

#logo h2 {
    display: inline;
}

#logo a {
    float: right;
    color: rgb(255, 200, 0);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 10px;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: rgb(255,200,0);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
}

</style>    
</head>

<body>    
<div id="logo">
    <p>
        <img src="picture.jpg" >
    </p>        
    <h2>SUBSCRIBER PORTAL</h2>      
    <a href="#">LOG-IN </a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT US </a>     
</div>    
<div id="navigation">
    <p>
        This is just a navigation test.
    </p>
</div>    
<div id="contents">    
    <p>This is just some dummy text. Dummy. </p>        
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/qTyGn/

Comment: I want the image to be on the left column with the h2 directly after it centered vertically. I want the two a tags to also be centered vertically, but right aligned.

Comment: The navigation bar (#logo) you provided has the property `width:100%;`. And you want it to be centered? Centered with respect to what? Viewport?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're looking for, but check this out. Based on what I am guessing you want. http://jsfiddle.net/qTyGn/1/

Comment: It's really hard to know what you're looking for. Update your question based on something concrete, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qTyGn/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) give the `img { vertical-align:middle; }`. also remove the

around the img.
2) have you tried `padding:0;`?.
3) `padding-bottom:-<value here>px;` or you could try just `padding:0;` or `padding-bottom:0;`.
I'm not sure about the questions, because they are not really setup well.

Comment: I was able to tweak the properties and get the image and h2 to line up centered vertically. I cant get the a tags, however, to do the same on the right side, even with the vertical-align:middle statement set.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: absolute; in your CSS for your navigation and logo or a tags to specify exactly where you want them to appear. Such as this example:

```
 #logo {
 position:absolute;
 top: 170px;
 left: 300px;
}
```